# How to delay preMove for each file detected using SFTP?

Tags: apache-camel, sftp, delayed-execution

I have the following situation: I need to add a 30 second delay everytime a file is detected by a SFTP route.
The route is as follows for now:

```
sftp://username@host:port/path/to/import/directory
?password=password&moveFailed=/path/to/error/directory
&move=/path/to/success/directory
&preMove=/path/to/inProgress/directory
&delay=30&initialDelay=30&useFixedDelay=true&timeUnit=SECONDS
```

How should I do if I want the 30 second delay to be applied independently to the detection of each file?
For example:

- t0: File 1 dropped
- t10: File 2 dropped
- t30: File 1 moved and rest of
  processing start
- t40: File 2 moved and rest of processing start

Thanks so much in advance!

Tried everything I could find

Comment: Would you explain why you need to delay before processing a file?  Is it to avoid reading an incomplete file that another process is currently writing?  In that case, would [readLock=changed](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/ftp-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_readLock) help?

Comment: It is a feature that our client wants us to implement. In order to take back a file before processing if they realize they put it there by mistake, I guess :)

Comment: Add a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635528/57719) to the SFTP consumer so it includes only files older than 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks @ChinHuang, that's a good place to start! :)
But I seem to only be able to use file:modified, as something resembling file:added isn't supported by the Simple language and I need to check the added date, not the modified date :/